# Logged in user perform segue not working user data using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I am actually trying to perform segue if the user is logged in to the home page and the segues are connected and I have given identifier as "loggedin"
and I have not currently coded for logout so there is no way of clearing `NSUserDefaults` and I have checked that too it gives my value back!!

Below is my view did load method of first view controller in this I am getting mobile number from user for otp

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.custid =[defaults objectForKey:@"uid"];
    NSLog(@"Customer id--%@",self.custid);
    if(self.custid!=nil)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loggedin" sender:self];
    }

    [_checkboxb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unsigned checkbox"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkboxb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signed check box"]
                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
}
```

this is my storyboard and in log u can see the error
[image: this is my screenshot]

and my code of that view controller is executing not the first view the logged in is executing but the view is of first view controller

Comment: Don't check user login status in first view controller. Check login status in appdelegate and assigh root view controller according to that.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR where do u suggest me to use root view controller??

Comment: In AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Comment: performsegue will not called in vieDdidLoad Method. Pls call it in viewDidAppear Methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check user login status in first view controller. Check login status in `AppDelegate` and assign root view controller according to that.

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
  UIViewController *viewController;
  NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  if([defaults objectForKey:@"uid"]!=nil)
  {
    viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
  }
  else
  {
    viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
  }
  self.window.rootViewController = viewController;//With out NavigationController
  //self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];//With NavigationController
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: is that identifier segue's identifier?? or view controller id??is it storyboard id of vc??

Comment: @Akshay No. It is viewcontroller's identifier

Comment: I cleared nsuserdefaults and logout option is in tableview of my menu its like 5th vc

Comment: @Akshay Why do you want to perform segue to otp view after logout?

Comment: if the user wants to login with diff id r sth like that

Comment: is it possible to achieve this??

Comment: Yes. You can perform segue to any view controller in logout button action.

Comment: I m really sorry I did that and actually I gave identifier wrong so it didn't work!!!lol:) thank you for ur help and u can upvote if it was a valid question